# Get default value from dropdown when page loads

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a value from a dropdown when my page loads. I have an (onChange) event which gives me the value but only when the dropdown value is selected.

Here is my code

```
<p>
  <p-dropdown (onChange)="getRetirementPercentage($event)" [options]="memberContributionPercentages">
  </p-dropdown>
</p

ngOnInit() {
  this.retirementService.data.subscribe(data => this.isDismiss = data);
  this.getRetirementPercentage(event);
}

getRetirementPercentage(event) {
  this.percentage = event.value;
  this.totalContribution = this.ctc * (this.percentage / 100);
}
```

How would I get the default value in the dropdown?

Comment: use ngmodel or keep a reference to access the element

Comment: can you explain more? default value means?

Comment: On page load you need to pass a default value for your dropdown say using ngModel. now if you change the drop down value update ngModel value with it.

Comment: @skydev search for template driven or reactive forms you'll know what to do.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda the value that is in the dropdown when the page loads. The values come from an endpoint. The first value in that endpoint is the default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ngModel two way data binding like this...

```
<p>
     <p-dropdown (onChange)="getRetirementPercentage($event)" 
                 [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
                 [options]="memberContributionPercentages">
     </p-dropdown>
</p>
```

then in your component.ts file...

```
this.selectedValue = 'defautl value'
```